# File Access Time is not getting modified in File explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, filesystems, ntfs

I am trying to figure out the last access time for file in Windows if user read the file. I know that to improve the performance of NTFS filesystem in Windows vista and above the last access times of files and directories are not updated.

To enable Last Access timestamp for files and folder in Windows we have to run the following command and need to restart the computer.

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
```

Even after restarting the computer the last access timestamp for file is not getting changed if I open and close the file.

If any one have any idea about how to enable last access timestamp then please let me know.

Comment: "The NTFS file system delays updates to the last access time for a file by up to 1 hour after the last access." from [File Times - Windows applications | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/file-times)

Comment: @DavidPostill I have already gone through it, but for me it is not working. The last access time is getting modified when I refresh the parent directory of file from file explorer.