# Last Access Time on Windows 7/10 not updating

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, ntfs, timestamp

The last access timestamp does not change when reading/opening/editing without saving a file in both Windows 7 (32-bit, NTFS) and 10 (64-bit, NTFS).

I did use:

```
fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess
```

to enable LastAccessTime, restarted the machine and got a 0 when executing:

```
fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess
```

The only time this last access timestamp changes (is different from the last modify time) is when I copy the file (creation and modify date are the same as the original). Am I missing something or is this normal?

Comment: Did you restart after running those commands? Also last access time stamp is not instant, it takes time in Windows before it changes the metadata.

Comment: Possible dupe....https://superuser.com/questions/1414295/file-access-time-is-not-getting-modified-in-file-explorer

Comment: @Moab it is like 5 hours and 3 restarts ago. Both OSs are on dualboot on one machine but there is no linux (heard it messes up the time settings). Could there be something wrong with the processor or ssd? and i am also confused that windows managed to change last access on the copied files

Comment: @fly_over_32, how big is the drive where you enabled last access time? I think there are some rules in NTFS that prevent last access time from being updated on small drives.

Also, note that the last access time in NTFS only has a granularity of an hour or so, so perhaps the update you were expecting to happen was too close in time to the previous last access time?

Comment: @Moab the drive has 500GB so around 250 per OS. and last time i checked was 16hrs ago. Still nothing. But i have a bigger problem now. Windows 10 does not accept my password anymore (or maybe someone just changed it without telling me) so i guess there is something seriously broken :(. This is why i use Linux on my home machine.